# How to align images in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong in this syntax? I am trying to get the logos to render on one line vs them stacked on top of another.

I have created a jsfiddle if this helps in what I'm trying to explain: [logos](https://jsfiddle.net/nickfs000/1v44xr5g/)

HTML

```
   <div id="images">
      <div class="AuthorizeNetSeal"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id="a502c38f-5a39-422d-aa53-a363d6e0fcbax";</script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js" ></script></div>
      <div><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup" title="How PayPal Works" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/na/us/logo-center/9_bdg_secured_by_pp_2line.png" border="0" alt="Secured by PayPal" /></a></div>
      <div><a href="//www.shopify.com/pci-compliant?utm_source=secure&amp;utm_medium=shop" title="This online store is secured by Shopify" target="_blank"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/images/badges/shopify-secure-badge-light-shadow.png" alt="Shopify secure badge" width="138" height="60" /></a></div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
images {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: simply remove the divs wrapping your images

Comment: white space is not used for element positioning. [white-space css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: all these suggestions are great and have also implemented into my syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```css
div#images div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
      <div class="AuthorizeNetSeal"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id="a502c38f-5a39-422d-aa53-a363d6e0fcbax";</script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js" ></script></div>
      <div><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup" title="How PayPal Works" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/na/us/logo-center/9_bdg_secured_by_pp_2line.png" border="0" alt="Secured by PayPal" /></a></div>
      <div><a href="//www.shopify.com/pci-compliant?utm_source=secure&amp;utm_medium=shop" title="This online store is secured by Shopify" target="_blank"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/images/badges/shopify-secure-badge-light-shadow.png" alt="Shopify secure badge" width="138" height="60" /></a></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This syntax was simpler to implement and worked like a charm!